# RTMP , RED5 multicasting

Tags: ffmpeg, multicast, rtmp, red5

I am trying to implement multicast on a red5 server specific to an application called Bigbluebutton. It uses RTMP for audio, video and texts.

problem: I cant use flash media server to implement the multicast as the software has some ties with RED5.

Is there any other way to implement multicasting on application layer level using these two protocol within a local network?

Regards,
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTMP does not allow multicast natively and it will be a very painful project to implement multicasting by yourself on client side. But there are two solutions :

1. You could try RTMFP multicast serverless solution. Here is a good example explained by Tom Krcha : http://tomkrcha.com/?p=1803 (just add a NetStream and attach the camera to it),
2. Otherwise you could try Adobe Media Server or [MonaServer](http://www.monaserver.ovh/installation.html#download) (our open source server) to use NetGroup and RTMFP. I think that re-implementing the server part of Bigbluebutton should be easy.

EDIT: RTMFP with NetGroup is the only simple solution to have multicast (P2P broadcasting) on the internet.

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Comment: Is there any tutorials for integrating Monaserver with bigbluebutton??